# Backbone model is not rendering default? Need Jade and Backbone gurus

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

Hey so I am having a problem where my templates change but the backbone model does not seem to provide the info I need. I am trying to solve this so I can move on to making collections. I am not getting any errors and I am using handlebars but have tried underscore's templating as well and the problem doesn't lie there but against the info displaying. When I click edit and the edit template shows it is showing undefined for #{firstName} and the others.

Main.js file

```
(function () {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates: {},
        Router: {}

    };

    // MODEL
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'first',
            lastName: 'last',
            email: 'Email',
            phone: '222',
            birthday: 'date'
        },

        validate: function (attrs) {
            if (!attrs.firstName) {
                return 'You must enter a real first name.';
            }
            if (!attrs.lastName) {
                return 'You must enter a real last name.';
            }
            if (attrs.email.length < 5) {
                return 'You must enter a real email.';
            }
            if (attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
                return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
            }
            if (attrs.city.length < 2) {
                return 'You must enter a real city.';
            }
        },

        initialize: function() {
             this.on('invalid', function (model, invalid) {
                console.log(invalid);
            });
        }

    });


    //VIEW
    App.Views.User = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#user',
        //model: userModel,
        //tagName: 'div',
        //id: 'user',
        //className: 'userProfile',
        //template: _.template($("#userTemplate").html()),
        //editTemplate: _.template($("#userEditTemplate").html()),


        initialize: function (){

        },


    render: function() {
        this.template = Handlebars.compile($("#userTemplate").html());
        this.editTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#userEditTemplate").html());

        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click button.edit': 'editProfile',
    //  'click button.save': 'saveEdits',
        'click button.cancel': 'cancelEdits'
    },

    editProfile: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));

    }, 

        //saveEdits: function (e) {
        //  e.preventDefault();

        //  var formData = {},
        //      prev = this.model.previousAttributes();
//

            //get form data
        //  $(e.target).closest('form').find(':input').not('button').each(function(){
        //      var el = $(this);
        //      formData[el.attr('class')] = el.val();
        //  });

            //update model
        //  this.model.set(formData);

            //render view
        //  this.render();

            //update array
        //},

        cancelEdits: function() {
            this.render();
        }

    });
    //start history service
    Backbone.history.start();

    var user = new App.Views.User({model: new App.Models.User()});
    user.render();
})();
```

Jade file

```
extends layout
block content   
    div.centerContent

        h4 User goes here with equal before it no space
            div#user
                p #{firstName} #{lastName}
                p #{email}
                p #{phone}
                p #{birthday}
                button.edit Edit

        script(id="userTemplate", type ="text/template")
                p #{firstName} #{lastName} 1
                p #{email} 2 
                p #{phone} 3 
                p #{birthday} 4
                button.edit Edit

        script(id="userEditTemplate", type ="text/template")
            div
                form(action="#")
                    input(type="text", class="firstName", value='#{firstName}') 
                    input(type="text", class="lastName", value='#{lastName}')
                    input(type="email", class="email", value='#{email}')
                    input(type="number", class="phone", value='#{phone}')
                    input(type="date", class="birthday", value='#{birthday}')
                button.save Save
                button.cancel Cancel
        hr
        script(type="text/javascript", src="/js/main.js")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing this line from your view

```
model: App.Models.User,
```

You are trying to assign a Backbone function directly to your view.

Also the problem is because of this line in your render method..

```
render: function() {
       var template = Handlebars.compile($("#userTemplate").html());
       var editTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#userEditTemplate").html());
```

The editemplate is local to the `render` method and not available in other methods.

```
editProfile: function () {
     this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
},
```

You are trying to access the template using `this.editTemplate` , but the variable is local to the render method and not to the view.. So you are not able to access it..

Instead of creating it in the local scope, instantiate to the view it self so that it is available in other methods of the view.

```
render: function() {
      this.template = Handlebars.compile($("#userTemplate").html());
      this.editTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#userEditTemplate").html());
```

Then it should be available to the other methods as well in the same view.

Comment: Ok I added the this. and changed it around as you can see in the code. Also, I made a new var called userModel and set it to a new App.Models.User(); and then called it in the view. However, I am still getting the same results with none of the default model's values being shown. The 1,2,3,4 next to the P tags show but the actual #{firstName} etc. does not show still

Comment: Remove the line `model: userModel,` from your view completely.. You are already passing the model required when the view is being initialized... Also views are ignorant of the models... So it need not know what type of model it is being passed in.. You are already passing it in `var user = new App.Views.User({model: new App.Models.User()});`

Comment: Ok removed the model file from the view and updated the code above. Thanks. Still getting nothing though

Comment: Try putting a debug point in the browser and inspect using developer tools.. Check the contents of the model after you click edit

Comment: I put console.log(user) at the end and it seems that the default values are not being displayed. Is there something I have to do? When I added a new var u = to the model and then call u.defaults the values are then printed otherwise they are blank. Trying to replace the App.Models.User() with that model too would cause an error because there is no .toJSON method it would say... any clue... So it is a 100% because the model's default values are not being called for the model's values, but I do not see what I am doing wrong

Comment: Try adding this line in the initialize method and see if it fixes the issue..  `_.bindAll(this, editProfile)` in the initialize method of the view

Comment: Yeah doesnt do anything : /

Comment: Can you create a diminished working fiddle if possible.. Cannot possibly solve it blindly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xj8br/ That is the best I can do, the problem is I don't know how to enable jquery also and jade.

Comment: Check thie fiddle.. Seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/xj8br/1/ .. Using underscore templates.. This is the one with Handlebars  http://jsfiddle.net/xj8br/2/

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I forgot this around the variable {{ firstName }} I was using this #{firstName} that was the solution thanks again!